# Creating a mongoose model containing array types return undefined for those in my docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I have a mongoose model containing 2 properties Array of String and some others:

```
var Model = new Schema({
    _id: {type: Number, required: true, unique: true}, 
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    oneList: [String],
    anotherList: [String]
});
```

I create the model:

```
var model = new Model({
    _id: 1,
    name: 'model',
    oneList: ['a', 'b'],
    anotherList: ['c', 'd']
})
```

but when I inspect the model all the list are undefined:

```
model._doc === {
    _id: 1,
    name: 'model',
    oneList: undefined,
    anotherList: undefined
}
```

I tried some variations:

- change the model definition from [String] to [ ]
- create separately the data outside the model then pass it
- create the model without list data then add it to the model

Even when I create an empty model:

```
var model = new Model({})
model._doc.oneList === undefined
model._doc.anotherList === undefined
```

Context:
**The problem occurs on a docker container but not on my local machine**

node: v4.4.7

mongoose: v4.6.0

[GitHub](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4534)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, apparently when you have a nested array within your model, mongoose has an [open issue 1335](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1335#issuecomment-90991319) that saves an empty array when a property references a schema. I experimented with presaves to force the property to be an empty array if the property's length is 0 or undefined.

Also be careful when specifying `unique=true` in the property's schema, as empty or undefined properties will violate the indexing and throw an error.

Note:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var barSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  baz: String
});

var fooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  bars: [barSchema]
});

var Foo = mongoose.model('Foo', fooSchema);

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo); // { _id: 55256e20e3c38434687034fb, bars: [] }

foo.save(function(err, foo2) {
  console.log(foo2); // { __v: 0, _id: 55256e20e3c38434687034fb, bars: [] }

  foo2.bars = undefined;
  foo2.save(function(err, foo3) {
    console.log(foo3); // { __v: 0, _id: 55256e20e3c38434687034fb, bars: undefined }

    Foo.findOne({ _id: foo3._id }, function(err, foo4) {
      console.log(foo4); // { _id: 55256e20e3c38434687034fb, __v: 0, bars: [] }

      mongoose.disconnect();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok. I had a nested object in one of my models, I removed it and now it works. It's still annoying of not having an index there in terms of validation but if fixed the problem. Anyway, thanks for your help. I validate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var schema = new Schema({
        _id: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        oneList: [String],
        anotherList: [String]
    }),
    Model = mongoose.model('Model', schema),
    m = new Model();

m._id = 1;
m.name = 'model';
m.oneList.push('a', 'b');
m.anotherList.push('c', 'd');
```

Comment: m.oneList.push('a') returns 1, m.oneList.push('b') returns 2, but m.oneList and m._doc.oneList are still undefined